# Window ordering should not be confused with presentation ordering, it does not prevent the result from being relational

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In "TSQL foundamental 4th edition", the author mentioned that

> window ordering should not be confused with presentation ordering, it
>   does not prevent the result from being relational.

Due to my inexperience at SQL, I have unable to figure out on my own, the reasons behind this statement. So I was just wondering if someone could kindly explain the logic to me?

Comment: This is just saying that the `ORDER BY` clause inside a partition will not necessarily have any impact on the ordering of records in the final result set presented to you.  As usual, Microsoft's documentation may be a bit cryptic.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thanks, that makes things a bit clear. So I guess "presentation ordering" prevent the result from being relational because it guarantees query result order (if the result is ordered, then it is NOT relational), but because "window ordering" does not guarantees query result order, therefore it does not prevent the result from being relational. lol that's a lot of words, but I hope i understood the concept correctly

Comment: Yes, the presentation ordering is the `ORDER BY` at the end of the query.